# Angular: Number of patches in the last 12 months?

Tags: angular, patch

i´m writing a Projekt about Angular (not AngularJS) and I have to evaluate the framework.i can´n find the answer to some criteria, maybe can someone help me.

How many patches have been released in the last 12 months?
How quickly are detected errors fixed?

if there are sources somewhere, pls write them.

THANX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find all answers here https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

Everything can be found at the following:

Changelog: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md 
NPM: https://github.com/angular/angular/releases